# Cannot #include due to nesting, cannot use class prototype

Tags: c++, vector, header, include

Situation: I have a Particle class and a Field class. Particles have fields associated with them, and vice-versa fields often have particles.

I cannot `#include "particle.hpp"` in `"field.hpp"` if I `#include "field.hpp"` in `"particle.hpp"`. This makes good sense, of course.

I resorted to using forward declarations in each of the two files, however the compiler now fails to compile with these errors:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ElementaryParticle’
error: forward declaration of ‘class ElementaryParticle’

error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ElementaryField’
error: forward declaration of ‘class ElementaryField’
```

Is there a work around to solve these problems? I understand why the error occurs. How can I define both classes without including them in each others files? These problems arise because field attempts to access members of particle, and particle contains a vector of fields.

EDIT: One workaround would be to merge the classes into one class in one file... But that would be ridiculous and lead to all sorts of other problems.

EDIT2: I know about header guards.

Comment: Include `particle` in `field`, and `field` in `particle`, but surround both the headers with [header guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)? I'm kind of confused by your question but I think this is what you want.

Comment: "Include the other header in each header" - This is the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: You can do that with header guards.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus Scott explained the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make field.hpp include particle.hpp, include a forward declaration of ElementaryField in particle.hpp - and then include field.hpp in your particle.cpp .  That should solve your problem, as long as you don't have any code in particle.hpp.  Technically, you could just do forward declarations of each in the .hpp, and then include the other's .hpp in the .cpp.  This might be better, since it's more standardized.  I went with my initial assesment since you said that field accesses members of particles, while particles just contain a vector of fields.

Also, if you're not using pragma [#once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), perhaps it would help?

Comment: Why should I use pragma #once rather than #ifndef ?

Comment: It's the same idea, just neater.  The important question is: why should you include one header in the other?  In this case, you resolve your issue by answering "I shouldn't."  Declare your dependency through forward referencing, then define it in you implementation.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Thanks for your help, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Fantastic mate, it does, cheers! Compiled no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most programmers use include guards when they define their headers.  Some compilers allow the

```
#pragma once
```

directive but if that's not available the common convention is to define #ifndef guards like as follows:

```
#ifndef PARTICLE_HPP__
#define PARTICLE_HPP__

class Field;

class Particle {
// ...
};

#endif // PARTICLE_HPP__
```

and

```
#ifndef FIELD_HPP__
#define FIELD_HPP__

class Particle;

class Field {
// ...
};

#endif // FIELD_HPP__
```

That done, you now have the issue of undefined classes within each context.  The solution here is to never assume the definition of particle in field and never assume the definition of field in a particle.  You have declarations, and that's fine.  But don't use anything that requires a definition.  For instance, in Particle.hpp, avoid:

```
Field x;  // Error: Requires Constructor definition
Field *y; // Okay
Field &z; // Okay, but must be initialized in constructor
y->foo(); // Error: Requires definition of foo
z.bar;    // Error: Requires definition of bar
```

Instead, put all those error bits in your .cpp which can include both headers and have the full definitions of both objects.  Keep your headers abstract with only pointers and references and you should be fine.